# Как определить версию ECMAscript?

Tags: javascript

Определить по имеющемуся коду. Мне это нужно для Google Closure Compiler, там можно указать версию ECMAscript.

Comment: в общем случае никак: например, `function(){...}` может быть использовано во всех версиях

Comment: @Grundy Это вы про функции в блоке что ли? Типа никаких новых операторов не используется, а мол результат разный. Ну да, я тоже думаю что не определить. Только если выучить все новые фичи ES6 и самому понять - используешь ты их у себя или нет.

Comment: Нет, это я про определение функции. Это определении _одинаковое_ во всех версиях. Поэтому нельзя будет указать конкретную версию.

Comment: @Grundy Не совсем понял про что вы. Я использую Google Closure Compiler (сжиматель кода) и чтобы он корректно сжал код ему можно передать версию ECMAscript специальным флагом, по умолчанию стоит ECMAscript6 что наверно не совсем верно если я его не использую.

Comment: И чем тебя не устраивает значение по умолчанию?

Comment: @Grundy Тем что я не использую ECMAscript6. Код, наверное, может быть сжат неверно из-за этого.

Comment: @Khipster а ты попробуй))  там скорее всего указывается не то, какая версия ecma используется, а *максимальная*. ты же ведь в es6 используешь то, что было придумано еще лет 5 назад и просто перекачевало в версию, Тип String например или Не-число (NaN) ........ или ты думаешь, что всё на корню вырубается и в другой версии совсем всё по другому и синтаксис и данные и переменные и объявление?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Нет, в GCC указано: "Sets what language spec that input sources conform. Options: ECMASCRIPT3, ECMASCRIPT5, ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT, ECMASCRIPT6 (default), ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT, ECMASCRIPT6_TYPED (experimental)". В ES6 всё таки и стандартные операторы могу вести себя по другому. Ну например уже упомянутые функции (Function Declaration) в блоке. В ES5 такие функции будут доступны и за пределами блока. => возможны ошибки при сжатии.

Comment: @Khipster, еще раз: никак нельзя определить по коду версию спецификации. Максимум минимальную версию, в которой введены новые функции или новые ключевые слова

Comment: @Grundy Что посоветуете?

Comment: в большинстве случаев дефолтное значение подойдет, можно даже strict версию пробовать

Comment: @Grundy Вы про ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT или про ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT?

Comment: в них не большая разница